# Unittest Matlab version 2011

Tags: matlab, unit-testing

I want to test a class which throws error but I use Matlab 2011b and I don't find matlab.unittest (to have matlab.unittest.TestSuite.fromFile).

What can I use ?

Comment: Will this work https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47302-xunit4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is write it as a [script based test](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/write-script-based-unit-tests.html). This way when you upgrade it will work out of the box with the test framework in newer versions. In the meantime, you can just run the test by invoking the script.

If you can't upgrade now, then you can write something like the following helper function to test for these errors in your script:

```
function assertError(fcn, errorID)

e = MException.empty;
try
    fcn();
catch e
end
assert(~isempty(e), 'No error occurred. Expected an error with the id "%s"', errorID);
assert(strcmp(e.identifier, errorID), ...
    'Wrong error occurred. Expected id "%s", but id "%s" was thrown.', ...
    errorID, e.identifier);
```

To test this out:

```
>> assertError(@()error('some:id','Some message'), 'some:id') % no failure 
>> assertError(@()disp(5), 'some:id')
     5

Error using assertError (line 8)
No error occured. Expected an error with the id "some:id"

>> assertError(@()error('other:id','Some message'), 'some:id')
Error using assertError (line 9)
Wrong error occurred. Expected id "some:id", but id "other:id" was thrown.

>>
```

Comment: I found this link and I try to do as explain. But, maybe I missed the information, how can I do if I want to test the code bellow :

'
function angles = rightTri(sides)

if(sides(1)<0 or sides(2))
   error('Sides have to be positive')
end
A = atand(sides(1)/sides(2));
B = atand(sides(2)/sides(1));
hypotenuse = sides(1)/sind(A);
C = asind(hypotenuse*sind(A)/sides(1));

angles = [A B C];

end
'

I don't find the way to test if the code throws the right error.

Comment: I think the best approach is to upgrade if you can, then you have rich capabilities that have all the features you need and are very robust. Then you have verifyError (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.qualifications.verifiable.verifyerror.html) and/or the Throws constraint (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.constraints.throws-class.html).